# Space and time variant? But together invariant?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames

I admit I'm having difficulty with spacetime. I don't understand how unifying space and time, seemingly variant quantities, results in an invariant spacetime. All texts and references talk about using velocity to make space and time measurable in the same units. I guess what I want to know is: does time dilate the same amount as space contracts as we travel faster?